# Programmatically register a nib from a custom table view cell defined in main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that has a custom UItableview cell which I defined in the Main.storyboard file.  When I use Search Display Controller, I need to register the class with the searchDisplayController's tableView inside viewDidLoad.  The custom table view cell is called "LargePostTableViewCell".

```
    self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(LargePostTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: LargePostTableViewCell)
```

However, I also need to register the nib file that is associated with LargePostTableViewCell, but that is defined in Main.storyboard.  In all the examples I saw, people defined separate nib files for the custom table view cell and was able to reference it that way.  Is is possible to reference a UINib for a custom table view cell that's inside Main.storyboard?  Here is my code for trying to register the nib file:

```
    self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "LargePostTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LargePostTableViewCell")
```

Comment: If the file is in the storyboard it is not a nib and does not need to be registered

Comment: but the searchDisplayController doesn't know about it if it's in the storyboard.  do I need to make a separate file for it, or is there a way to reference it directly?